# Unable to Send UDP packets on Android N

Tags: sockets, android-ndk, udp, rtp, android-7.0-nougat

I have an application to send UDP Packets, the socket is getting created properly but giving an error while sending the packets. The Application works fine for every version of Android except for Android N.

I am getting the following error  `SendTo() error: 13`.
Here is a part of the code:

```
bool Bind(const SocketAddress& name)
{
int size = sizeof(sockaddr);
std::cout << "Socket Reuse SET" << std::endl;
int yes = 1;
if( 0 == setsockopt(_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)))
{
    std::cout << "Socket set" << std::endl;
}

if (0 == bind(_socket, reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&name),size))
{
    return true;

}
_error = errno;
return false;


}

int32_t SendTo(const int8_t* buf, size_t len,
                               const SocketAddress& to)
{
    int size = sizeof(sockaddr);
    //std::cout << "Send TO [" << buf << "]" << std::endl;
    int retVal = sendto(_socket,buf, len, 0,
                        reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&to), size);
    if(retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        _error = errno;

    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. In particular, note that you need to send these packets on a background thread.

Comment: I am already working on background thread to send the packets.